# Getting ordered subset of records

Tags: sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have table which basically describes a bus route. The table includes all the stops of a particular route.

[This SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f8358) shows an example. The data shows the flow in one direction, but a route can also be in the other direction.

I need to get a subset of this route (or all of it) depending on the start and end stations. So for example, I might have these:

```
A -> M (subset would be B -> L)
A -> K (subset would be B -> J)
C -> H (subset would be D -> G)
I -> M (subset would be J -> L)
```

However, if the direction is from, for example, H -> B, the subset would need to be G -> C.

The sequence column is for this purpose.

Is there a clean and easy way to do this using just SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I understand your question, it seems simple enough.
To get a subset just use a `between...and` operator on the `sequence` column:

```
SELECT stop_from, stop_to
FROM routes
WHERE sequence BETWEEN 2 AND 11
ORDER BY sequence
```

To get the subset in the opposite direction, just order by desc, and select the `stop_to` as `stop_from`, and `stop_from` as `stop_to`:

```
SELECT stop_to As stop_from, stop_from As stop_to
FROM routes
WHERE sequence BETWEEN 3 AND 7
ORDER BY sequence DESC
```

[See fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f8358/9)